# How to have dictionary print out random keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
file = open(selection, 'r')
dictionary = {}
with file as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split(',')
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        dictionary[key] = values

n= int(input("How many words would you like to be tested on: "))
while n > length:
    print("Invalid. There are only" ,length, "entries")
    n= int(input("How many words would you like to be tested on: "))
print("You have chosen to be tested on",n, "words.\n")


for i in range(n):
    while len(dictionary)>0:
        choice = random.shuffle(list(dictionary.keys()))
        correctAnswer = dictionary.get(choice)
        print("English: ",choice)
        answer = input("Spanish: ")
        if answer.lower() == correctAnswer:
            print("Correct!\n")
            del dictionary[choice]
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            wrongAnswers.append(choice)
        break
print("\nYou missed", len(wrongAnswers), "words\n")
```

Hi, I am trying to create a vocabulary test on python, but when I run the code, instead of printing out the key, it just prints out "None" 
What can I do for the code to print out a random key?

Comment: You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: try some print statement at various points and see from where your dict is changing and not storing values.

Comment: `random.shuffle` works in-place and returns `None`, like `my_list.append(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use random.choice instead of shuffle.

```
choice = random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
```

shuffle changes the list you send into the function and since you don't save a reference to that list, you don't get anything. Also, it only generates a shuffled version of that list and not a single value.

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
random.shuffle(alist)
print(alist)

>> [2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Even better, drop the `list`, since `.keys()` returns a list.

Comment: @bozdoz not on Python 3 it doesn't

Comment: Wow, didn't know.  Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga. What an interesting jump it will be when I finally start using version 3. :D

Comment: Although, you *don't* need to call `keys` at all. Just `list(dictionary)` will give you a list of keys.